# How to Limit Upload File Size to Google Drive via HTML

Tags: html, file-upload, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to upload file to google drive using html form. I have found a solution [here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/11/06/uploading-local-files-to-google-drive-without-authorization-using-html-form/). It works well for me, but I would like to limit the file size and file category.  I have tried with these following codes:

```
<input type="file" size="15MB" />
<input type="file" max-file-size=123456789 />
<input type="file" size="15MB video/mp4, 256KB image/*" />
```

But these are not working. Actually I am very new in HTML or Javascript. How can I do this?

**Added:**  I want to update this code with file size limit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sample script for uploading file to Google Drive without authorization</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec" id="form" method="post">
        Upload a file
        <div id="data"></div>
        <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.fileName = file.name
        fr.onload = function(e) {
            e.target.result
            html = '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="' + e.target.result.replace(/^.*,/, '') + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="mimetype" value="' + e.target.result.match(/^.*(?=;)/)[0] + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' + e.target.fileName + '" >';
            $("#data").empty().append(html);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using .size property you can do this.

```
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {alert(this.files[0].size); });
```

Ones your got the size you can put warning and other messages on different conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where to add this code. Can you provide complete code example. @RonakBokaria

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/7jc9v2gL/  here it is. This is not mine but it's good. Using this you can show the selected image as well the size of image.